# How to hide sorting arrows being displayed over checkbox column?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have done the following to no avail;

### Checkbox HTML

```
<th class="table-checkbox sorting_disabled" aria-label=" " style="width: 24px">
    <div id='emails_table_checker' class="checker">
        <span class="">
            <input class="group-checkable" type="checkbox">
        </span>
    </div>
</th>
```

### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var table = $('#emails_table');
    table.dataTable(
    {
        "aoColumns": [
            {   "sClass": "center",
                "mRender": function (data)
                {
                    if (data == '1')
                    {
                        return 
                        '<input type="checkbox" checked value="' + data + '">';
                    }
                    else if (data == '2')
                    {
                        return 
                        '<input type="checkbox" value="' + data + '">';
                    }
                },
              "bSortable": false },
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": true },
        ],
        "pagelength": 10,
        "pagingType": "bootstrap_full_number",
        "language": 
        {
            "lengthMenu": "  _MENU_ records",
            "paginate": 
            {
                "previous":"Prev",
                "next": "Next",
                "last": "Last",
                "first": "First"
            }
        }
    });

    var checker = $("#emails_table_checker");
    checker.click(function()
    {
        if (checker_status)
        {
            checker_status = false;
            table.$('span').attr('class','checked');
        }
        else
        {
            checker_status = true;
            table.$('span').attr('class','');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

The above code renders the checkbox in the header in such a way that;

- Tick never shows up however many times you click on it.
- An up arrow for sorting shows up on the right side. It reacts on clicking to a down arrow and vice versa. It doesn't call the sorting function though.
- Clicking any other column's head makes the arrow to go away permanently until page refresh.

I want the tick to show up and the arrow to go away, can somebody help please.

Comment: what version of datatables are you using?

Comment: @davidkonrad where can i check? It came embedded in a theme we bought, Metronic v3.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are disabling sorting a little bit wrong, I think. Adding `.sorting_disabled` to a `<th>` manually is useless; the proper way of disable sorting for a particular column is like this (1.10.x) :

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
   ...
   aoColumnDefs : [{
      orderable : false, aTargets : [0] //disable sorting for the 1st column
   }],
   order : [] //disable default sorting, eg sorting on 1st column  
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/99h8u/**

The problem in the previous answer was, that datatables apparently sort by the first column by default, even if sorting for this column is turned off.

---

**Update**. To adjust the width of a column, the proper way is to use `aoColumnDefs`, or `aoColumns`, not setting the width as inline style in `<th>`  (here the first column as above):

```
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
   aoColumnDefs : [ {
       sWidth: '24px', bAutoWidth: false, bSortable : false, aTargets : [0]
   }]
});
```

***If*** you have long strings in the column, and dataTables insists of a larger width, add this CSS (again for the first column) :

```css
table.dataTable tr td:first-child  {
    word-wrap: break-word; 
    max-width: 24px;
    overflow-x: hidden;    
}
```

the demo from above with forced 24px width on 1st column -> **http://jsfiddle.net/97M94/**

Comment: am completely new to css, can you tell where should I place the css code?

Comment: it does go away but the width of the column remains the same, with checkboxes a little bit to the left of the center median.

Comment: @UmairAhmed, have updated the answer so you dont have to use CSS for hiding the arrow. It was not a bug in 1.10.x, I found out on datatables.net, thanks to datatables author Allan Jardine, just another approach. Updated with a solution for forcing a shrinked column width.